# React test not working with current Jest config, Gatsby and gatsby-theme-i18n

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, gatsby, react-testing-library

I am fairly new to testing with Gatsby and Jest and I am encountering issues with my current setup.

I am trying to build a site with Gatsby and I would like for CI purposes to run unit tests with Jest and react-testing-library.

I initially was able to run a simple test:

```
describe('<Header>', () => {
  describe('mounts', () => {
    test('component mounts', () => {
      const { container } = render(
        <Header />
      );
      expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

 describe('click', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Header />);
    expect(screen.getByText('Light mode ☀')).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent(
      getByText(container, 'Light mode ☀'),
      new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      }),
    );
    expect(screen.getByText('Dark mode ☾')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

where my render is a customized one:

```
const AllTheProviders = ({ children }) => {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(true);
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        dark,
        toggleDark: () => setDark(!dark),
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';

// override render method
export { customRender as render };
```

and the Header a simple component that consumes the context and toggles the theme from dark to light.

I since then added `gatsby-theme-i18n` to handle i18n and tweaked my jest config to add:

`transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(gatsby-theme-i18n)/)']`

The Header is now wrapped in a `Layout` component that provides the locale and location (with the Help for `Location` and `@reach/router` that comes with Gatsby) so I can have a language toggle in the header

In the Layout:

```
import { Location } from '@reach/router';
[...]
 <Location>
  {(location) => (
    <Header
      siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
      location={location}
      locale={locale}
    />
   )}
</Location>
```

The Header makes use of `LocalizedLink` from gatsby-theme-i18n` to prefix the right locale

```
  <li key={langKey}>
    <LocalizedLink key={langKey} to={to} language={langKey}>
      {langKey}
    </LocalizedLink>
  </li>
```

I also changed the test to:

```
describe('mounts', () => {
    test('component mounts', () => {
      const { container } = render(
        <Location>
          {(location) => (
            <Header siteTitle="site title" location={location} locale="en" />
          )}
        </Location>,
      );
      expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

However, I get an error when trying to run the test:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'themeI18N' of undefined

      21 |
      22 | const customRender = (ui, options) =>
    > 23 |   render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });
         |   ^
```

specifically coming from at `useLocalization (node_modules/gatsby-theme-i18n/src/hooks/use-localization.js:9:7)`

where the Gatsby theme provides the i18n info through a graphQL query:

```
 const {
    themeI18N: { defaultLang, config },
  } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      themeI18N {
        defaultLang
        config {
          code
          hrefLang
          dateFormat
          langDir
          localName
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

I understand that Jest does not 'understand' what to do with the i18n passed through the `gatsby-theme-i18n` via the Layout and if I switch my `LocalizedLink` to a normal Gatsby `Link`, the test passes (and I can console.log the container to see it's indeed a React element with the right info).

I tried a few things I saw online like using `const { useLocalization } = require('gatsby-theme-i18n');` but to no avail.

Any idea how to handle this?
Should I mock the utils from `gatsby-theme-i18n` like other elements from Gatsby are mocked (Link etc.) [following the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/unit-testing/#3-useful-mocks-to-complete-your-testing-environment)?

#### EDIT

Thanks to the author of the library, LekoArts, and a friend a mine, I managed to make it work :)
If somebody has the same issue, you need to mock the response from the useStaticQuery of the useLocalization hook.

I have a mock file that does it:

```
// Libs
const React = require('react');

const gatsby = jest.requireActual('gatsby');

// Utils
const siteMetaData = require('../src/utils/siteMetaData');

module.exports = {
  ...gatsby,
  graphql: jest.fn(),
  Link: jest.fn().mockImplementation(
    // these props are invalid for an `a` tag
    ({
      activeClassName,
      activeStyle,
      getProps,
      innerRef,
      partiallyActive,
      ref,
      replace,
      to,
      ...rest
    }) =>
      React.createElement('a', {
        ...rest,
        href: to,
      }),
  ),
  StaticQuery: jest.fn(),
  useStaticQuery: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    site: {
      siteMetadata: {
        ...siteMetaData,
      },
    },
    themeI18N: {
      defaultLang: 'en',
      config: {
        code: 'en',
        hrefLang: 'en-CA',
        name: 'English',
        localName: 'English',
        langDir: 'ltr',
        dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      },
    },
  })),
};
```

and my test:

```
// Libs
import React from 'react';

// Utils
import { Location } from '@reach/router';
import { render, fireEvent, getByText, screen } from './utils/test-utils';

// Component
import Header from '../header';

describe('<Header>', () => {
  describe('mounts', () => {
    test('component mounts', () => {
      const { container } = render(
        <Location>
          {(location) => (
            <Header siteTitle="site title" location={location} locale="en" />
          )}
        </Location>,
      );
      expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  describe('click', () => {
    test('toggle language', () => {
      const { container } = render(
        <Location>
          {(location) => (
            <Header siteTitle="site title" location={location} locale="en" />
          )}
        </Location>,
      );
      expect(screen.getByText('Light mode ☀')).toBeInTheDocument();
      fireEvent(
        getByText(container, 'Light mode ☀'),
        new MouseEvent('click', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
        }),
      );
      expect(screen.getByText('Dark mode ☾')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

You can find [more information here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/themes/issues/43#issuecomment-666982539)